Go GIO widget mouse events not working with pointer receiver
go version
go version go1.20.2 darwin/arm64

I'm following an example here in order to learn Widgets in Go.  For the interactive portion, I first made the mistake of not using a pointer receiver for the Layout method.  I was using print statements to inspect the events to understand why I couldn't drag the bar that splits the two widgets and realized that setting
s.Ratio = deltaRatio

wasn't saving the state. When I would click and drag, nothing happened. But I was able to see all of the filtered events (Press, Drag, etc) being logged like so:
Event: {Cancel Mouse 0 Shared 0s  (0,0) (0,0) }, ok: true
Event: <nil>, ok: false
Event: {Press Mouse 0 Grabbed 395h40m22.184483375s ButtonPrimary (794.6953,579.84375) (0,0) }, ok: true
Event: {Cancel Mouse 0 Shared 0s  (0,0) (0,0) }, ok: true
Event: {Cancel Mouse 0 Shared 0s  (0,0) (0,0) }, ok: true
Event: <nil>, ok: false
Event: {Drag Mouse 0 Grabbed 395h40m22.313367916s ButtonPrimary (795.1406,579.84375) (0,0) }, ok: true
Event: {Cancel Mouse 0 Shared 0s  (0,0) (0,0) }, ok: true
Event: <nil>, ok: false
Event: {Drag Mouse 0 Grabbed 395h40m22.321639958s ButtonPrimary (795.96094,579.84375) (0,0) }, ok: true
Event: {Cancel Mouse 0 Shared 0s  (0,0) (0,0) }, ok: true
Event: <nil>, ok: false
...

I changed the Layout method to use the pointer receiver
func (s* Split) Layout(...)

but now, when I click and drag, the only logs I see are Cancel events:
Event: {Cancel Mouse 0 Shared 0s  (0,0) (0,0) }, ok: true
Event: <nil>, ok: false
Event: {Cancel Mouse 0 Shared 0s  (0,0) (0,0) }, ok: true
Event: <nil>, ok: false
Event: {Cancel Mouse 0 Shared 0s  (0,0) (0,0) }, ok: true
Event: <nil>, ok: false

...

Does anyone know why this would happen?  I'm new to Go and still trying to figure all this out.
For a little more context, here's where I added the log I've show in the code for the link
ev, ok := gtx.Event(pointer.Filter{
    Target: s,
    Kinds:  pointer.Press | pointer.Drag | pointer.Release | pointer.Cancel,
})
if !ok {
    break
}
fmt.Printf("Event: %v\n", 

Please let me know if any other info would help
